# Custom Button wouldn't resize as expected android

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I created a custom button class in purpose to set the height of every instance of this class to the biggest one depending on the text that will be written in the button. here is my custom button:

```
 public class QuestionAButton extends Button {

    /* ... Constructors */

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec,
                             int heightMeasureSpec) {
        //TODO Here I ll be doing some customisation about the proposition Button
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        resizeThemAll();
    }

    private static int maxHigh = 0;
    private static ArrayList<QuestionAButton> instances;

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        if (instances == null) instances = new ArrayList<>();
        instances.add(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        instances.remove(this);
    }

    private static int maxHeigh = 0;

    public static void resizeThemAll() {
        int maxHeight = 0;
        if (instances != null) {
            for (QuestionAButton tmp : instances) {
                if (maxHeight < tmp.getMeasuredHeight()) maxHeight = tmp.getMeasuredHeight();
            }
            for (QuestionAButton tmp : instances) {
                tmp.setHeight(maxHeight);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I expected that once a button is created it verifies if its height is the max between all the unprecedentedly instantiated buttons, if so it will set the maxHeight value to it heigh and resize all the other instances but its doesn't work as expected. Any help? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I advice you to take a look at "The View's life cycle" in android. Here is a [link](http://ndquangr.blogspot.com/2013/04/android-view-lifecycle.html).

Your solution: You need to override onSizeChanged(int,int,int,int) by invoking your resizing method inside that callback.

Some code to demonstrate:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    resizeThemAll();
}
```